# How to use functions with arrays correctly

Tags: c, matrix

This is a small program that I wrote to add 2 square matrices.

When i input the second matrix the values of the first are altered and the result is subsequently false. It works quite well for 2x2 matrices,But not for any bigger matrix.
The algorithm works well without the use of functions.
Please help me solve this problem.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
void PrintMatrix(int P[n][n])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", P[i][j]);
        }
    }printf("\n");
}
void ReadMatrix(int P[n][n])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("input row %d\n", i+1);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
        scanf("%d", &P[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void AddMatrix(int P[n][n], int Q[n][n], int Result[n][n])
{
   int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        Result[i][j]=P[i][j]+Q[i][j];
      }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int A[n][n];
    int B[n][n];
    int Sum[n][n];

    printf("input matrix size:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("input first matrix\n");
    ReadMatrix(A);
    PrintMatrix(A);

    printf("input second matrix\n");
    ReadMatrix(B);
    PrintMatrix(B);

    AddMatrix(A,B,Sum);
    PrintMatrix(Sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C needs to know the width of the matrix at compile time, it can't be a variable.

Comment: @Barmar Except it doesn't need to know the width at compile time, it can be a variable. VLA, welcome to the year 1999 :)  But of course there are many cases where VLAs aren't suitable.

Comment: @Lundin OK, but he needs to declare the matrix variables **after** he reads `n`, doesn't he?

Comment: @Barmar Yes indeed, the array declaration has to be on the right side of the dimension variables, see my answer below.

Comment: I knew about VLA, but I thought it only applied to the first dimension.

Comment: I'm talking about the declarations of `A`, `B` and `Sum` in `main`.

Comment: @Barmar Same applies there, they can have non-constant dimensions as long as they have automatic storage duration. Static storage duration variables must have compile-time constants as dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own matrix type with a struct, such as for example:

```
typedef struct
{
  int*    data;
  size_t  width;
  size_t  height
} matrix_t;
```

Or if you have a modern C compiler, you can write the functions like

```
void func (size_t width, size_t height, int matrix[width][height])
```

But the struct version is probably to prefer.

---

**EDIT**

As for why your program is buggy, you must initialize `n` to a value. If you declare the arrays as variable-length arrays of size [n][n] *after* the point where you read `n` from the user, it should work fine.

Comment: `int matrix[width][height]` - `width` and `height` should be constant or not? modern C standard allows variable-length array to function parameter?

Comment: @ikh They don't have to be constant, modern C has the concept of variable-length arrays.

Comment: C99 accepts variable-length array as function parameter, as long as the length parameters come BEFORE the array itself. GNU C specifically has a syntax extension that allows for parameter forwarding, like: `void func (size_t width; size_t height; int matrix[width][height], size_t width, size_t height) {...}`; in this case, `width` and `height` are formal parameters that should be passed AFTER `matrix`, and are merely declared beforehand.

Comment: It still doesn't work. the problem still remains the same. When I read the values of the second matrix, I values of the first are altered. and I have no idea why it is like that.

Comment: @Gladson Ah, turns out it was just a trivial bug. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you run this under gdb here is something you'll find
(gdb) p A
$14 = 0x7fffffffdfb0
(gdb) p B
$15 = 0x7fffffffdfa0

irrespective of whatever "n" you choose the array base address always differ by 16 that is integer 2 x 2 matrix works

but if i Input length as 3 the program crashes. There is memory corruption. 
before doing input 
(gdb) x/12 A
0x7fffffffdfb0: 0   0   -255260739  52
0x7fffffffdfc0: -1  -1  -1  -1
0x7fffffffdfd0: -8272   32767   -1  -1

after input:
x/12 0x7fffffffdfb0
0x7fffffffdfb0: 1   2   3   4
0x7fffffffdfc0: 5   6   7   8
0x7fffffffdfd0: 9   32767   -1  -1
is fine as i gave values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but
 p A
$16 = 0x7fff00000009
is this accessing it causes segmentation fault in PrintMatrix.

now if you change your program to this

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;

    printf("input matrix size:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int A[n][n];
    int B[n][n];
    int Sum[n][n];
```

your problems are solved and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the help. At least that's a good explanation for the bug. got to admit I didn't understand much of it. I'm still a beginner. :)